# Play framework: is there a way to avoid strange form helper syntax?

Tags: java, forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to build a form with Play Framework 2, the [usual syntax](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaFormHelpers) is:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit, 'id -> "myForm") {   
}
```

Note that the single quotation mark is before id is opened and never closed.

Is there another syntax that I can use to do the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `'id` is a [`Symbol`](http://www.scalalang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Symbol).

You *could* use the `Symbol("sym")` syntax if you don't like this one, but it is not standard.

```
scala> 'symbol == Symbol("symbol")
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess that it's like writing `new String("string")` instead of `"string"`, but it is much less disturbing and compatible with most common editors.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* work around it with an implicit conversion. This will require using a scala source file, though (seems like you're using java, but you can mix them).

**app/libs/SymbolImplicits.scala**

```
package example.libs

object SymbolImplicits {
    implicit def string2Symbol[A](s: (String, A)): (Symbol, A) = (Symbol(s._1), s._2)
}
```

Then in your view you would `@import example.libs.SymbolImplicits._`, so you can then do:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit, "id" -> "myForm") {   
}
```

`"id" -> "myForm"` is then implicitly converted to `'id -> "myForm"`.

To avoid using that import in every view, you could also add this line to `build.sbt` (or in `Build.scala` project properties) instead:

```
TwirlKeys.templateImports += "example.libs.SymbolImplicits._"
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that's required syntax for Scala's [Symbol](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Symbol.html) as pointed in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918617/1066240), anyway except that it looks *weird* for it's perfectly valid and there's no reason to fight with it.